# Python:Error calling class variable in a staticmethod

Tags: python

I am trying to call a class variable within a staticmethod, but when I called I am getting an error *"hello" is not defined*. any advise ?

```
class hello:
    random1 = []

    @staticmethod
    def sub(x):
        hello.random1.append(x -1)

    sub.__func__(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(hello.random1)
```

Comment: Yes, because *the class `hello` doesn't exist when it's class body is being executed*

Answer (score 1):

`hello` doesn't *exist* as a global name until you dedent out of the class definition (at which point the class is created and assigned to the global name `hello`). Change the code to:

```
class hello:
    random1 = []

    @staticmethod
    def sub(x):
        hello.random1.append(x -1)

hello.sub(2)
```

so `sub` is invoked *after* `hello` exists, and it will work.